# Is there a way to express the inverse of harmonic numbers $1/H_k$ as a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

The series for harmonic numbers $H_k$ is:

$$
\frac{1}{1-z}\ln{\frac{1}{1-z}}
$$

which then gives the series:

$$
1z + \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)z^2 +\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)z^3 + \ldots
$$

However, I encountered a problem which asks for the inverse of the harmonic series $1/H_k$ ... is there any series for the inverse of the harmonic numbers?

Comment: Can you cook up any *simple* example of $\sum_n a_n z^n$ with $a_n\asymp1/\ln n$? (Let alone the exact thing.)

Comment: @metamorphy, sorry I was looking at another series so that was a mistake. $H_k$ it's divergent, but the question still stands since it asks for a series that is close to $1/H_k$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ even if $H_k$ is divergent.

Comment: Closely related: [Numerator of harmonic number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497703/numerator-of-harmonic-number)  As you will find there, the numerator of a harmonic number relative to the obvious factorial denominator can be given in terms of Stirling numbers.  Exchanging the roles (make factorial the numerator and Stirling number expression the denominator) might be what you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\frac1{1-z}\log \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\, z^n$$ Make the long division to get
$$\frac{1}{z}-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{5 z}{12}+\frac{z^2}{24}+\frac{11 z^3}{720}+\frac{11
   z^4}{1440}+\frac{271 z^5}{60480}+\frac{13 z^6}{4480}+\frac{7297
   z^7}{3628800}+\frac{425 z^8}{290304}+O\left(z^9\right)$$

For large $n$, you can use
$$\frac 1{H_n}=\frac{1}{\log (n)+\gamma }-\frac{1}{2 n (\log (n)+\gamma )^2}+\frac{\log (n)+\gamma
   +3}{12 n^2 (\log (n)+\gamma )^3}-$$ $$\frac{2 \log (n)+2 \gamma +3}{24 n^3 (\log
   (n)+\gamma )^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ For $n=10$
$$\frac 1{H_{10}}=\frac{2520}{7381}\approx 0.341417152$$ while the above would give                                     $0.341417101$

Comment: This will seem like an extremely stupid question, but how can we use your first series, $1/\sum_{n \geq 1} H_n z^n$, to obtain $\sum_{n \geq 1} (1/H_n) z^n$ ? Oh I get it ! We evaluate $1/f(1/z)$ ?

Comment: I also note that this question has been asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1202434/159855

Comment: Pardon, Claude, what is a "long division"?

Comment: Does this actually answer the question or am I missing something here?